# swift initializer optional and non-optional at the same time?

Tags: swift, initializer

https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper requires me to have

```
 required init?(_ map: Map){
 }
```

I'd like to instantiate `Foo()` but it is Foo? type not Foo.

I added the following initializer but no avail.

```
 override init() {
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a convenience init instead of overriding the existent one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** edit ** 
Sorry for the false call..

I had problem with the below code.

```
 var foo = Mapper<Foo>().map(jsonString)
 if foo != nil {
     return foo!
 }

 foo = Foo()
 return foo
```

I think the problem is when i declared `var foo` it's declared as `Foo?` type and `foo = Foo()` is still `Foo?`

so I changed the code to

```
 var foo = Mapper<Foo>().map(jsonString)
 if foo != nil {
     return foo!
 }

 return Foo()
```

and it seems working.

Answer (score 1):

Take the Foo?, check if it has a value, and then unwrap it.

```
let ff : Foo? = Foo()
if ff != nil {
    let f : Foo = f!
    // ...
}
```

Or more simply:

```
let ff = Foo()
if let f = ff {
    // ...
}
```